# Partial template specialization of std::atomic for smart pointers

Tags: c++, c++11, atomic, smart-pointers, c++20

## Background

Since C++11, atomic operations on `std::shared_ptr` can be done via `std::atomic_...` methods found [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/atomic), because the partial specialization as shown below is not possible:

```
std::atomic<std::shared_ptr<T>>
```

This is due to the fact that `std::atomic` only accepts [*TriviallyCopyable*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/TriviallyCopyable) types, and `std::shared_ptr` (or `std::weak_ptr`) is not trivially copyable.

However, as of C++20, these methods have been deprecated, and got replaced by the partial template specialization of `std::atomic` for `std::shared_ptr` as described [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/atomic2).

## Question

I am not sure of

1. Why `std::atomic_...` got replaced.
2. Techniques used to enable the partial template specialization of `std::atomic` for smart pointers.

Comment: Were the `std::atomic_...` methods removed in C++23?

Comment: @user2023370: I've seen nothing in C++23 drafts that say that they are removed. They're [still in the deprecated section](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/depr.util.smartptr.shared.atomic).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several proposals for `atomic<shared_ptr>` or something of that nature explain a variety of reasons. Of particular note is [P0718](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0718r0.html#2.0), which tells us:

> The C++ standard provides an API to access and manipulate specific `shared_ptr` objects atomically, i.e., without introducing data races when the same object is manipulated from multiple threads without further synchronization. This API is fragile and error-prone, as `shared_ptr` objects manipulated through this API are indistinguishable from other `shared_ptr` objects, yet subject to the restriction that they may be manipulated/accessed only through this API. In particular, you cannot dereference such a `shared_ptr` without first loading it into another `shared_ptr` object, and then dereferencing through the second object.

[N4058](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4058.pdf) explains a performance issue with regard to how you have to go about implementing such a thing. Since `shared_ptr` is typically bigger than a single pointer in size, atomic access typically has to be implemented with a spinlock. So either every `shared_ptr` instance has a spinlock even if it never gets used atomically, or the implementation of those atomic functions has to have a lookaside table of spinlocks for individual objects. Or use a global spinlock.

None of these are problems if you have a type dedicated to being atomic.

`atomic<shared_ptr>` implementations can use the usual techniques for `atomic<T>` when `T` is too large to fit into a CPU atomic operation. They get to get around the TriviallyCopyable restriction by fiat: the standard requires that they exist and be atomic, so the implementation makes it so. C++ implementations don't have to play by the same rules as regular C++ programs.